# How to get path outside from Angular project

Tags: angular, angular6

My Image folder is outside form Angular project. I need to provide path of image on img tag.

```
<img src="../../mydir/imges.jpg">
```

Comment: Images needs to be located in a folder declared as assets of the projects in `angular.json` files, and all paths start from the `index.html` page. This would give `src="mydir/images.jpg"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using glob.

```
"assets": [
{"glob": "**/*", "input": "../../outsideDirectory", "output": "./assets/"}]
```

This will copy all assets outside the folder into the output directory mentioned.

Now you can use you code as

```
<img src="assets/image1.png">
```

Though "image1" was outside the folder it will get copied in the dist/assets folder hence the program will work.

If you need to access images in some other way then you should host those images and use in your src tags.

[wiki link for the same](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration)